# I want to know how to join Pro_ID and location ID with multiple tabel

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I wrote this code for one data tabale name "Purchase" i want to link location names, productnames, purchase qty,tfr qty & sales Qty

```
SELECT location_tbl.location,product_tbl.pro_name,SUM(purchase_tbl.Qty) AS Total_Purchase From((purchase_tbl Inner Join location_tbl ON purchase_tbl.Location_ID = location_tbl.Location_ID)Inner Join product_tbl ON purchase_tbl.item_ID = product_tbl.Pro_ID)GROUP BY location_tbl.location,product_tbl.pro_name;
```

[This is the example table and view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wbBr.png)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but to answer ur question u first need to clearly define. You have refered each table primary key as ID. But when u r using that ID into another table u again call it ID. It would be great if u could clearly name each table ID as itemID, storeID so that when u use it another table it is easy to understand. Right now i cannot identify what is the flow in ur data.

Comment: could you please see the photo i have uploaded

Comment: I have 5 tables.1 for the product list, /  2 for the location list. /  3 for the purchase date. / 4 for the stock transfer data, and 5th for sales data.   so i want to get available stock from that tables. calculation is  purchase+stock TFR To- Stock TFR From - Sales = Avilable Stock